# Wordpress redirect to static index.html page while keeping sub-pages intact?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

Wordpress newbie here and building on this, I have a similar problem to the question asked here:

[under construction page on index while working with WordPress on root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14602227/under-construction-page-on-index-while-working-with-wordpress-on-root-folder)

Working with Wordpress for the first time for a client. They have been using Wordpress (installed by another designer whom they've lost touch with) and want to return to having a static html page, but want to keep the ability to log in and make subpages for their clients. The subpages wouldn't be private pages, but rather "if you know it's there and have the link" kind of pages.

Currently they have www.domain.com go to index.php but want it to redirect to a separate, static index.html design I've created for them. Is this possible to do in the .htaccess file without disrupting the rest of the Wordpress set up? I fear breaking something and being unable to fix it and losing what they have so far. Currently reading up on WP and watching every video tutorial I can to learn more!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: generaly you can set this via the host? setting which pages are most important, ie: index.html (1st), index.htm(2nd), index.php(3rd)

just move index.html to 1st position above index.php it should load your static file, or you can do it via htaccess and override the apache settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put this line at the top of the `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

It will swap the order in which Apache prioritises the files.

Comment: Inside or outside the #BEGIN Wordpress? Thanks

Comment: @smendiola `#` are comments so it shouldn't matter.  `.htaccess` directives are sequential instructions, as you want to set the directory index before anything else just place it right at the top of the file and move everything else down a few lines - more organised that way.

Comment: Then... if no index.html file exists it will behave as normal - otherwise it will prioritise it.

Comment: worked beautifully, thank you so much! :)